# Using mod_proxy_ajp for a java portal on Tamcat+Apache

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, mod-proxy-ajp

I have a java portal running on Tomcat but I want its static contents(except html) to be served by Apache httpd.
So I've installed an Apache httpd and now I am configuring httpd.conf
I know that I need something like the below text:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
ServerName mywebapp.com
ServerAlias mywebapp.com
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.gif)$" "ajp://localhost:8009/$1"
ProxyPassReverse  /  ajp://localhost:8009/
```

But this is a sample and I do not know how to use RegEx in front of **ProxyPassMatch** to fulfill my purpose.

My purpose is to serve **jpg, jpeg, gif, js, css** by Apache httpd
And **others** serving by Tomcat

Comment: Are you sure you should have the argument to ProxyPassMatch in quotes like that? 

ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.gif)$   ajp://localhost:8009/$1  

If that doesn't work let me know and I'll get a local example running and will formulate an answer. (or someone else may post one before then ofcourse)

should do it I think

Comment: In my test both models worked (with and without quotes), but in Apache documents it has quotes. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: ok that's new... the doc page I had open for mod_proxy didn't :) fair enough.

and I see that your issue was to get more than 1 type of extension matched. I thought you had an error in config. my appologies I could've easily helped with that

Comment: No problem. Thank you @Joeblade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
    ServerName mywebapp.com
    ServerAlias mywebapp.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    #ProxyPass         /  ajp://localhost:8010/
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*(?<!\.jpg)(?<!\.png)(?<!\.jpeg)(?<!\.css)(?<!\.ico)(?<!\.bmp)(?<!\.js)(?<!\.gif))$ ajp://localhost:8009/$1  

    ProxyPassReverse  /  ajp://localhost:8009/
</VirtualHost>
```